# How to access 'related_name' of a model via intermediate model's Foreign key inside template tag?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  ...

class Review(models.Model):
  paper = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_class_related_name')
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  comment = RichTextField()
  status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default='draft')
  ...

class TrackReviewRequests(models.Model):
  paperid = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_track')
  numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
  ...
```

**views.py**

```
reviews_in_draft = Review.objects.filter(paper__active=True).filter(status='draft')

return render(request,
                  'accounts/profile.html',
                  { 
                      'reviews_in_draft': reviews_in_draft,
                  })
```

**profile.html**

Here I **tried accessing the 'numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent'** using the following code:

```
{% for review in reviews_in_draft %}
  {{ review.paper.book_track.numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent }}
{% endfor %}
```

**But I am getting empty string.**

Then I wrote a **method inside the Book model**

```
def get_TrackReviewRequests_numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent(self):
    return self.book_track.numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent
```

and tried accessing the *numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent* in the *profile.html* using the following code:

```
{{ review.paper.get_TrackReviewRequests_numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent }}
```

**But this time I got the error stating**

```
'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent'
```

Ultimately, I want to access the *numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent* in the template using the context variable.

Comment: A `Book`can have _multiple_ `TrackReviewRequests` hence `review.paper.book_track` is not an instance of `TrackReviewRequests` but as the error says a `RelatedManager`.

Comment: Can you try `review.paper.book_track.first().numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent` in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Book`can have *multiple* `TrackReviewRequests` (Since `TrackReviewRequests` has a foreign key to `Book`, if in reality there can only be *one* then you should use a [`OneToOneField` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) instead) hence `review.paper.book_track` is not an instance of `TrackReviewRequests` but as the error says a `RelatedManager`.

Hence when you write `review.paper.book_track.numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent`  it doesn't make much sense. You can instead *loop* over the related instances if you want in the template like so:

```
{% for review in reviews_in_draft %}
    {% for review_request in review.paper.book_track.all %}
        {{ review_request.numberOfTimesReviewRequestSent }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```